# Centering or manually positioning dynamic controls on a WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to create Labels that are centered around different columns on a Canvas. This code looks plausible:

```
string[] titles = { "Acorn", "Banana", "Chrysanthemum" };
double col = 20.0;
foreach (string s in titles) 
{
    var lbl = new Label() { Content = s };
    lbl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, col - (lbl.Width / 2.0));
    myCanvas.Children.Add(lbl);
    col += 150.0;
}
```

But it does not work because the `lbl.Width` (and `lbl.ActualWidth`) aren't calculated until rendering, which is long after the Labels are being created.

Is there a way to get the accurate `Label.Width` prior to a layout operation? On a `Canvas` there isn't all the control layout and flow you get with Grids or StackPanels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to ask the component what size it wants to be with the Measure method. If you specify unlimited available space with the double.PositiveInfinity value, you can then use the control's DesiredSize property to get its ideal, unclipped, unflowed size.

This code shows the working solution:

```
  string[] titles = { "Acorn", "Banana", "Chrysanthemum" };
  double col = 20.0;
  foreach (string s in titles) {
    var lbl = new Label() { Content = s };
    lbl.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    lbl.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, col - (lbl.DesiredSize.Width / 2.0));
    myCanvas.Children.Add(lbl);
    col += 150.0;
  }
```

Comment: I've edited your answer and changed `double.Infinity` to `double.PositiveInfinity`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get the width before a layout pass... But what you could try is setting the `Label` to `Visibility` of `Hidden` (not `Collapsed`), then attach a `Loaded` event, and set its position then change back the visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
double pos = Canvas.GetLeft(lbl);
```

I'm not sure if this works before the layout pass, but worth a shot